# Angular Application Loading speed is high when compare to mobile with Desktop

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, single-page-application, angular6, pagespeed

We have built a [website](https://therightdoctors.com) with Angular6, Material Design & CSS. Our Website Loading Speed was 18secs, to decrease the loading speed we optimized CSS files & Optimized images, then it came to 12-13 secs. We want to decrease the loading speed, so we implemented Lazy Loading from [this](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) link. Now website loading speed is 8 secs.

Question 1:

How to decrease the page Load speed (<8secs)?

Problem: When we open any one single Page from the website directly, then that page it is taking 12 secs to load. How to decrease the loading speed in Mobile.

[link](https://therightdoctors.com/wccicc-2017/the-interview/emcure-dr-sb-gupta-stress-ECG-testing)

Question 2:

Why is it taking more time in mobile?

Page load:

[image]

Comment: You are not using aot, are you? Your vendor.js file is 7MB, unminified. Use AOT, it'll shrink its size. And use gzip compression on your server too

Comment: Use a browser that shows you the details from page load. Should be quite obvious from the picture I added to the question.

Comment: @David... Our website is an Angular Universal App, the Universal app itself have AOT compilation. As you suggested, i have used gzip compression. Now the page is loading with 8secs. Text Data is loading fast(2-3sec), but to load Video it is taking more time(6-7 secs). Please suggest us some solution.

Comment: I checked the link and there is no gzip compression, and no prod mode

Comment: @David.. Thank you for yours reply.. We enabled production mode, Speed came down now for inner pages. But after loading page, It is taking time to load video on Videogular Player. Here is the link(https://www.therightdoctors.com/wccicc-2017/in-conversation/emcure-dr-ramakrishnan-hk-chopra-mona-bhatia-in-conversation-role-of-ct-angio-in-predicting-cardiac-risks).. Please check and suggest some solution.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help with that. Maybe post a more specific question